# Can't affect declared variable

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make a method which returns int variable, but the method doesn't effect the variable.

This is my code:

```
int count;
public int getVotesForEvent(final String event_title) {
    firebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.child("Votes").exists()) {
                boolean flag = false;
                for (DataSnapshot event : dataSnapshot.child("Votes").getChildren()) {
                    String event_title2 = event.getKey();
                    if (event_title2.equals(event_title)) {
                        flag = true;
                        Toast.makeText(EventInfo.this, ""+Integer.parseInt(event.child("event_votes").getValue().toString()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        count = Integer.parseInt(event.child("event_votes").getValue().toString());
                    }
                }
                if (flag != true) {
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
            else {
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    });
    return count;
}
```

The problem is that the line:

```
count = Integer.parseInt(event.child("event_votes").getValue().toString());
```

This line is not effecting the variable `count`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's the value of "event_votes"?

Comment: Try to describe more in detail what exactly you expect to happen. Do you expect that AFTER calling `getVotesForEvent()` the value of `count` will be changed? Because it will not :)

Comment: Someone from inside firebaseRef will call `onDataChange()`. Only if this happens you will see a chenge in your variable.

Comment: Is your `Toast` showing up.. aka is the code in the if statement definately run.

Comment: And change your `onDataChange()` method like this to test it: 
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    count = 5;        
}

Comment: @user1301428 event_votes=1.

Comment: @HonzaZidek - I am trying to make the after calling getVotesForEvent() the value of count will be changed.

Comment: @Doomsknight - My Toast is showing up.

Comment: The call happens asynchronously. For a **great** explanation, see [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Hi, it's in JavaScript and it's hard to me to understand what I am doing in my code. Can you please have a look in my code and tell me what would you change in it?

Answer (score 1):

The method `getVotesForEvent()` itself **does not** call the code inside. So the value of `count` is not changed as your code returns from `getVotesForEvent()`.

The methods only adds a ValueEventListener (as its name suggest :) ) with the defined behavior.

Only **after** an `onDataChange` event occurs, the code inside is performed.

There is no sense in returning `count` from `getVotesForEvent()`, it will just return the value which was there at the time you called *that* method, not when the value of `count` changes (sometimes in the future).

To repeat in other words: when calling `addValueEventListener()`, you are *not executing* the code it contains. You are only "loading" the code to be executed later, whenever the respective event occurs.

Think about your code as this:

```
int count;
public int getVotesForEvent(final String event_title) {
    firebaseRef.addValueEventListener(what-shall-be-done-sometimes-in-the-future-when-onDataChange-event-occurs);
    return count;
}
```

and here you clearly see that the value of `count` is not changed.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But what changes do you recommend me to make in my code above?

Comment: But op said he can see the Toast message inside that method, so the code is being executed.

Comment: Yes, It is getting in to the "if()".

Comment: Have you tried what I had suggested in the comment? Change your onDataChange() method like this to test it: `public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { count = 5; }` I mean remove all the other logic you have there and leave *only* the assignment to the count. Or you may have there `count++`. I still do not understand the meaning of returning `count` from `getVotesForEvent()`, it will just return the value which was there at the time you called *that* method, not when the value of `count` changes.